# Why a blackened Platinum wire changes it's color gradually due to heating?

Tags: experimental-physics, thermal-radiation

A blackened Platinum wire , when gradually heated first appears dull red , then blue and finally white , why?

Answer (score 2):

According to Wien's displacement law, When blackened Platinum wire  is gradually heated, it first emits radiation of longer wavelength , so it appears red at higher temperatures it emits blue radiation more strongly than red and appears blue. At very high temperatures, it emits all radiation strongly and appears white.